# Blank image when trying to save UV unwrapping

Tags: uv

I had completed UV unwrapping so I tried to save the unwrapped image but after saving I looked at the saved image and it is fully blank. Why?

Uv unwrap is this:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you were trying to save the UV Layout? Can you show us what steps you used to do that? As it stands, there is not enough information in the question to answer.

Answer (score 1):

A UV map is an overlay, it doesn't belong to the image. If you want to save the UV layout as an image, click *UV* -> *Export UV layout*:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to UV mapping so i don't know if this will help

make a new material
then make a new texture 
add the image you are trying to unwrap then it should work

(sorry if i was unclear)